# Branching from origin/master vs branching from local master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Assuming we have a remote repository and we clone it locally.

We checkout a **`master`** branch so now we have the local **`master`** and a remote **`remotes/origin/master`**.

I then have to create a new **topic** branch that will be merged into the remote master once reviewed:

What are the pros and cons of branching from the local **`master`** vs the remote equivalent (if there is any difference)?

Do the same arguments apply to **long running** branches?

**EDIT:**

I have been trying to track **`origin/master`** for my local branches and I noticed a big downside: on TFS it doesn't let you create a pull request. If you want one, you need to push your branch to origin and this will detach it from master and it will track the new remote branch and then create a pull request; is there anything wrong in what I stated? If not, then this is a big reason not to branch from **`origin/master`**.

Comment: There is a difference most answers below are ignoring if you also set tracking information for the new branch: the behavior of `git pull` and `git push` . Note that tracking is usually set up automatically when branching off a remote reference, but not from a local one.

Comment: @AndréSassi Depends on how you branch off that remote branch.

Comment: I think most of the answers make too much light of assuming the local master is up-to-date.  It's easy to commit random things onto a local `master` and forget about them.  It may not be a huge deal if you're creating branches manually, but if you were to automate things more (e.g., a script that integrates with your ticketing system) and provide this automation to many users, you almost certainly want to use `origin/master`.  Why bother assuming `master` is up-to-date and not out-of-sync when you don't have to?

Comment: @AndréSassi what is the different behaviour of pull/push when tracking?

Comment: @Uno `git push` and `git pull` without any other arguments (depending on your configuration) will push to and pull from the remote branch the local branch is set up to track. For topic branches, either you never publish that (so you don’t need to track a remote), or you publish it as a topic branch itself (in which case it would track its own remote e.g. `origin/my-topic`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `master` is up to date with its remote tracking branch `origin/master`, there is no actual difference at all.

Branches are just pointers to commits in the history, so when branching off one branch, you are just creating another pointer that points at the same target. That pointer has no relation to the “original pointer/branch”; it only points to a commit. So when you continue working on that new branch, new commits will only reference the base using the parent relationship of commits. The branches itself are completely irrelevant to the history.

Git has a way to add some kind of metadata to branches. However, the standard branching mechanisms, e.g. using `git branch` or `git checkout -b`, will not make Git append *any* additional metadata to the branch.

The only relevant metadata would be the remote tracking branch. But usually, you wouldn’t want to have more than a single branch track the same upstream branch.

So in your case, when you are creating a feature branch or something, just branch off `master`, or `origin/master`. It doesn’t really matter.

Comment: What if master and origin/master are not in sync? Would it be just the same as pulling the changes from origin/master to master and then merging my branch?

Comment: If they are not in sync, then branching off `master` will place the new branch on the same commit as `master` is, and branching off `origin/master` will place the new branch on that one’s commit. It will not affect neither `master` nor `origin/master`. When merging, it depends on the order you merge things. For example, if you branched off `origin/master`, then did some work, and finally merge that new branch into `master`, then you are indirectly also pulling in the changes from `origin/master` (from that time) into `master`.

Comment: When you indirectly pull changes from origin/master, potentially they can conflict with my topic branch changes; in this scenario, would there be any difference with the two approaches?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean with “indirectly pull”. When you’re on your topic branch, and you pull in changes from `origin/master`, then there’s no difference what the base branch was.

Comment: I was quoting your comment: "then you are indirectly also pulling in the changes from origin/master".

Comment: Oh, right. With that, I only mean that those changes that exist on `origin/master` but not on `master` are also included in your topic branch (when you branch that off `origin/master`), so when you merge that topic branch later, you would also include those changes. If `master` did not diverge, then you should not get any conflicts; if it did diverge, you would get the same conflicts you would get when just pulling `origin/master` onto `master`.

Answer (score 2):

Running `git fetch` will always bring `origin/master` up-to-date, so preferring `origin/master` is probably correct in most environments.  When using topic branches for all development I find a local `master` is annoying because I feel compelled to update it from time-to-time even though it's useless, and therefore I prefer to just delete it.

A possible reason for preferring a local `master` as a base for development is that you do have more control over it.  If someone does an erroneous force push to the remote `master` you are likely to notice it when you try to merge it into your local `master` whereas `origin/master` will just automatically point to the new history.  Or maybe you want a stable base for development while still being able to fetch upstream changes?

Comment: One reason for having a local `master` would be the ability to merge *in* topic branches…

Comment: Good explanation for preferring origin/master; I am not sure I understand your point in favour of local branch, can you please clarify it? (if someone does an erroneous force push...)

Comment: @poke, you don't really need it for that; just checkout `origin/master` and merge.  You'd be working on a detached head, but you're only creating the single merge commit before pushing--no need to name that.  It's really the same argument: a local `master` takes a bit more effort to ensure it is up-to-date, something that is even more important when merging (verses when creating the branch.)

Comment: @Uno, if you're always using topic branches for development, then a local `master` should always fast-forward when pulling.  If someone overwrites the remote `master` with a different history you will notice this because your local `master` cannot be fast-forwarded.  I don't think this is a particularly strong argument for using a local `master`--if erroneous force pushes are a problem in your environment you have bigger issues.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the local master branch is up-to-date with the remote branch, there is no difference. Both will be at the commit/point-in-time, so is doesn't matter from which one you start.

However if you've made local changes to the master branch that aren't guaranteed to be merged into the remote branch that your new branch merges in to, you might want to start from the remote reference. In this case there is a difference between the two since the two branches contain different commits.

In general the rule is that you start a branch from the branch you want to merge back into in the end. If you track the remote branches 1-on-1 local vs. remote won't make a difference.

Comment: So basically I should branch from the one I'm not likely to change? What problems can I have if I branch from local master and them make changes to it? Just more maintenance to push the changes from the new branch into the remote without including the new commits on master?

Comment: @Uno As explained in my answer, the new branch does not have a relationship to the branch you based it on. When “branching off”, you just choose a base *commit* (not a branch) which happens to have a temporary name (the branch).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any absolute pros and cons. You're just starting with the history from one branch or another. Local master is the master branch on your PC. The remote master is just the master branch on your remote PC (server, etc). They are both just branches local to the machine they are on that share the same name.

The only difference is the remote *acts* as a hub across multiple users. I emphasize acts because nothing in git forces that remote branch to be a "hub". It just happens to be used as a hub by your team as a convention.

There may be some subtle advantages like you may be able to set your upstream branch implicitly by branching from one or the other.  Or you don't need to worry about your local master branch not being completely up-to-date with the remote by branching directly from the remote.

Given all that, I'm not even sure how you spin off a branch based on a remote branch instead of a local branch... but assuming it can be done, the above should be accurate =).

Comment: What scenario can cause problem if local master is not up-to-date with origin/master and I branch from local?

Answer (score 0):

No difference as such, normally if you want to create a new branch say Branch1, you will checkout master with latest commit locally in your system from git server, checkout master code to a new local branch named Branch1 and push Branch1 to the git server after commit. The point here is to make sure you have master code up-to-date.